# Raspberry Pi Cores Usage for OpenCV - FaceRecognition

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi3

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 and developing standard LBPH face recognition (not face detection) algorithm to id the face. When I run my `htop` I can see that all of my 4 cores are ~100%.

I am trying to increases the speed at which face recognition and detection happens for more real-time results and though of threading. But on normal operations all my cores are maxed out I do not see a point of threading. Please correct me if I am wrong, but it seems that raspberry pi 3 has a glass ceiling when it comes to Face Recognition in real time?

I am presently trying to implement DLib correlation tracking to recognized faces to hopeful get some speed.

Comment: For facial detection you need to keep a model loaded in your memory at each instant, and Dlib alone has a model of 100MB disk space, I don't guess it would feasible for an IoT device to perform efficiently, So I would recommend you to utilize the Networking utility of RasPi and off load the frames to a server machine for processings, So that all the processing power of your device is used in increasing FPS and not some other heavy memory operations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I completely understand that the raspberry pi has powerful networking capabilities that I can leverage. But my project has to be portable in nature with a smaller form factor. Hence I want build a system local to the chip and not leverage the networking capabilities.